# Having trouble converting integer color for cyan to RGB

Tags: java, colors, rgb, modulo, modulus

There is a simple algorithm to convert integer values to RGB value of three numbers between 0-255 at [integer to rgb](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58690/convert-int-to-color). I got the integer number from [Android Colors](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html). I even ran:

```
System.out.println(Color.decode("-16711681"));
```

and the answer was java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=0], which is expected.

I literally have an issue on step one, -16711681 % 256 is 255, and I expect 0 for the red color. In Java I coded:

```
System.out.println(-16711681 % 256);
```

and I get -1, which means I have to add 256 and my red color is 255. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why are you using decimal literals to represent colors? `0xFF00FF00` is much more clear than `-16711681`.

Comment: I am sending colors over a websocket and it just seemed simple to get the getRGB() method on my Colors in Java and send them to my client. I was planning on extracted the RGB on the javascript client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your number is not an ABGR-packed int like your link to gamedev suggests, but an ARGB-packed int.

the `Color.decode(int)` wants a color in the following format:

```
0xAARRGGBB
```

where `AA` is the transparency, `RR` is the red, `GG` is the green, and `BB` is the blue. When you execute `color % 256`, that returns the blue (`BB`) portion of the color.

If we look at the color with `Integer.toHexString(-16711681)`, we get:

```
 Color:   ff00ffff
(Format:  AARRGGBB)
```

Which is equivalent to `Color[r=0,g=255,b=255]`

If you want to read the red value, you need to shift it over first:

```
(color >> 16) & 0xFF
```

Comment: And the link that was provided that showed %256 was for something in `getABGRPackedInt()` -- AABBGGRR which is where the confusion lies.

Comment: @Alcanzar Indeed, since `Color.decode()` wants an `ARGB`-packed int :(

Answer (score 1):

Lets say  `x=-16711681`

The Binary value of `x` is `11111111000000001111111111111111`

```
Integer c = new Integer(-16711681);
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
```

Now, according to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#getRGB()) to get the `Red Value` we need to extract `16-23 bits` from `x`

[image]

---

**Qn:** How do i extract 8 bits from Positions 16-23 out of a 32 bit Integer?

**Answer:** `x = (x >> 16) & 0xFF;`

---

// Bits 24-31 are alpha, 16-23 are red, 8-15 are green, 0-7 are blue

Hence,  `Color.decode("-16711681"));` is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(((-16711681 >> 16) & 0xFF) + ":"
                + ((-16711681 >> 8) & 0xFF) + ":" + ((-16711681 >> 0) & 0xFF));
```

Output

```
0:255:255
```

Note that 
`System.out.println(Color.decode("-16711681"));`  outputs

```
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=255,b=255]
```